# Find value of a row by comparing two columns and a value with a range of a different dataset

Tags: r

I have 2 different datasets. One with an object that comes from a StationX and goes to StationY and arrives at a specific date and time as the following.

```
df1<-structure(list(From = c("Station1", "Station5", "Station6", "Station10"), To = c("Station15", "Station2", "Station2", "Station7"), 
                    Arrival = structure(c(971169720, 971172720, 971178120, 971179620), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -4L),class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In the Dataset2 are e.g. trucks which wait for the specific object at StationY between the time&date "Arrival" and "Departure" and leave at "Departure to a specifc region "TOID".
As in the following:

```
df2<-structure(list(TOID = c(2, 4, 7, 20), Station = c("Station15", 
                                                       "Station2", "Station2","Station7"), Arrival = structure(c(971169600, 971172000, 971177700, 971179500), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Departure1 = structure(c(971170200, 971173200, 971178600, 971179800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to look for the TOID in Dataset2 and add it to Dataset1 if "TO"(Dataset1)="Station"(Dataset2) and "Arrival"(Dataset2)<="Arrival"(Dataset1)<="Departure"(Dataset2) and has therefore the following outcome:

```
df1outcome<-structure(list(From = c("Station1", "Station5", "Station6", "Station10"
), To = c("Station15", "Station2", "Station2", "Station7"), `TO_ID` = c(2, 4, 7, 20), Arrival = structure(c(971169720, 971172720, 971178120, 971179620), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I need a solution which looks in dataset2 for the ID that matches the conditions regardless the roworder.

Would be awesome if you guys could help me how to code this in R.

Best,
J

Comment: Please post your data using `dput()` instead of pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `tidyverse`, use a `left_join` based on the `station`, and then `filter` based on dates:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("To" = "Station"), suffix = c("1","2")) %>%
  filter(Arrival1 >= Arrival2 & Arrival1 <= Departure1) %>%
  select(-c(Arrival2, Departure1))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  From      To        Arrival1             TOID
  <chr>     <chr>     <dttm>              <dbl>
1 Station1  Station15 2000-10-10 09:22:00     2
2 Station5  Station2  2000-10-10 10:12:00     4
3 Station6  Station2  2000-10-10 11:42:00     7
4 Station10 Station7  2000-10-10 12:07:00    20
```

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty new to R, so this code is probably longer then it should be. But does this work?

```
#renaming variables so its easier to merge the objects and to compare them
df1 <- df1 %>% rename(Arrival_Package = Arrival)
df2 <- df2 %>% rename(Arrival_Truck = Arrival)

#merge objects
df1outcome <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "To", by.y = "Station")

#subset from object and select relevant columns
df1outcome <- subset(df1outcome, Arrival_Package <= Departure1)
df1outcome <- subset(df1outcome, Arrival_Truck <= Arrival_Package)
df1outcome <- df1outcome %>% select(From, To, TOID, Arrival_Package)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I posted just an example where each row of dataset1 matches every row of dataset2. Your solution is not working if the data about the truck I am looking for is in row 500000. So I need a solution which looks in dataset2 for the ID that matches the conditions regardless the roworder.

Comment: Hi! I edited the code above. Let me know if it needs more adjustments.